# Windows service will only run when created from Visual Studio Release folder

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project that references a dll from another project.
I've also successfully created a service to start this app.

To create the service I simply ran a batch file that called the installutil.exe from the .net4 area and pointed it at the .exe in the Release folder of my VS project. The Release folder also contains a copy of the referenced dll.

With this arrangement everything works fine - I can access the dll through the service.

However, if I try to create the service from anywhere other than the Release folder it doesn't work.
To explain: 
I copied all the files from the VS Release folder into another unrelated folder and modified the paths in my install script. The service was created successfully and does start up. Unfortunately I cannot access the dll through the service when the service is created in this way. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can access the dll through the service"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if the current working directory was the Release folder when it worked. Perhaps it's because the working directory is not where the .dll file is in your broken scenario. Have you tried changing directories first, before calling the .exe?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. My VS project references the dll in its own project Release folder. My VS project copies this dll to its own Release folder when the project is built. I tested that I can run the app from the Release folder by running the .exe that is genereated as well as it running as a service. Copying all the files from my VS Release folder to any other folder and creating the service by pointing it at the new location creates the service as expected. It just won't work though. Are there other files that are required from the VS file system?

Comment: @user1167796 It's difficult to imagine all the possibilities... are you doing this from a command prompt or just double-clicking the .exe or batch file? Basically I'm asking if the working directory is set to where the .DLL file exists. Look at the properties for ANY program icon and you'll see a 'Start in' setting that presets the working directory to the same directory the program is in. I am wondering if the application works in the VS folder because it is already the working folder.